# replaceAll not working for below query

Tags: java

After executing the below line the `b` contains the value `"\%AMPAMP\$"`. I want it to be `"&"`. Please help.

```
String b = a.replaceAll("\%AMPAMP\$", "&");
```

Comment: Your question is not precise

Comment: what is contained in a? What d u want to represent by regular expression "\%AMPAMP\$"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). See the [public String replaceAll(String regex,String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Returns:
    The resulting String
```

You should do:

```
a = a.replaceAll("\%AMPAMP\$", "&");
```

---

**Edit**:

After you said that you did save it, you should now notice that `replaceAll` takes a **regex** and not a String. You should escape the [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) (Escaping a *regex* is done by `\`, but in Java `\` is written as `\\`), or use [String#quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
a = a.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\%AMPAMP\$"), "&");
```

Comment: Sorry for mistake i hav saved it

Comment: Do you mean i hav to do \& instead of &

Comment: @niknik123 yes exactly.That slash is for escaping that.

Comment: @WilliamFox Thanks a lot :) I'm honored.

Comment: @niknik123 Yes. But in Java, \ is written as \\.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need a regex here. Use [`String#replace(String search, String replace)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method like this:

```
b = a.replace("%AMPAMP$", "&");
```

btw `String#replaceAll` method needs a regex where you need to use double backslash to escape `$`:

```
b = a.replaceAll("%AMPAMP\\$", "&");
```